# Error: Waiting for group to become stable, current operations: creating: 4

Tags: redis, real-time, analysis, kubernetes

In the tutorial *Real-time data analysis with Kubernetes, Redis, and BigQuery on Google Cloud Platform*, when I run:
`$ kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.sh`, my terminal shows "Waiting for group to become stable, current operations: creating: 4". 
What is the problem? I have waited for the results for just half a day and tried it for several times, but it does't work!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13407
appears to be relevant. It sounds like you may need more CPU quote for your project. Please feel free to post details of your setup in that issue for additional help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get this error if there's a syntax issue in the startup scripts, which (since this tutorial has you edit the startup config info), you might have inadvertently introduced.
As a control, try first bringing up an 'out of the box' cluster with no config edits, and see if it comes up okay.